# To verify that nginx was successfully installed and is running as a service in Ubuntu. I run. “Sudo systemctl status nginx” = active: failed (result)

Tags: nginx

“Sudo systemctl status update”

**Active : failed (Result: exit-code )**
** systemd[1] Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server **

Comment: Look for nginx log

Comment: Check for the output `nginx -t`